# Insurance Claim on Sold Chametz

Tags: passover, money, chametz-leaven, selling-mechirat-chametz, hanaah-benefit

A Jew sells his chometz including an expensive non-kosher la'pesach whiskey collection located in a cellar.  A fire burns down the cellar and destroys all the whiskey.  The Jew makes a claim on his homeowner insurance and the insurance company sends a claim check for the loss on Pesach.  Can the Jew accept the money or would that be a problem of issur hana'ah from chometz?

Comment: What right did he have to submit the claim?? Sounds like straight up theft. Forget benefitting from Chametz

Comment: Why is he not entitled to make a claim on items covered under his insurance policy?  That is what he is paying his premiums for.  Assume in this example there is no insurance fraud and it was a legitimate loss and claim.

Comment: I'm with @DoubleAA. Sounds like he should pass the check along to the guy to whom he sold his chametz.

Comment: He can't claim damages on stuff he doesn't own!! What's confusing here? If I sell you my car and it crashes, can I file an insurance claim???

Comment: @donie no he has to give the check back, since his claim is invalid. If the owner of the whiskey wants to file a claim with his own insurance if he has, then good for him. That's a completely separate issue

Comment: I'm the eyes of the insurance company the Jew is still the owner of the whiskey. The sale was valid al pi halacha.  How does the non-Jew have any insurable interest in the whiskey if according to civil law he doesn't own it?

Comment: I am not sure, but there are 2 separate problems, regarding the insurance, its mine, regarding myself, its not mine. The reimbursement is a result from insurance conditions. Is there a rule which says that if the object was sold the insurance will not good. There is no Isur Hanaa from chamets which is not my chamets. @DoubleAA right?

Comment: @הבלשן Huh? In what way is the sale not valid? Everyone agrees the gentile owns the Chametz.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37219

Comment: What happens if he files the claim after Pesach?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to a case where he had a lot of stuff in the cellar that was insured, including the [sold] chametz, and the insurance company paid him for everything, including the chametz?

Comment: This is more a legal thing than a halachic one.   Namely, your homeowner insurance generally covers anything in your house *even if you don't own it*, as long as it is explicitly specified in the contract. 

Since the wine cellar in question is listed as "expensive", I would assume it is explicitly covered in the policy, (including appraised dollar value and a list of conditions under which it is expected to be kept).   As such, the money you get from the insurance company is because of the premium you pay every month.   "Ownership" doesn't really come into it.

Comment: Note:  In case of selling insured property (e.g. a car or a house), there's an issue that the liability has changed and you may have a case of insurance fraud.  In this case however, assuming there is no insurance fraud, then I would think you can take the money.

Comment: Often the sale is a conditional sale. That is, it is completed after Pesach if the non-Jew pays what he owes. Not sure of the implications of this though.

Comment: http://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=40350